# libprotobuf ERROR when training cifar10 on the windows Caffe

Tags: windows, protocol-buffers, caffe

Hi I'm new to DNN and I'm trying Caffe on windows 7. I have successfully compiled Caffe and also made train and test leveldb files of CIFAR10 and mean.binaryproto file. Now it's time to start train and test the CIFAR10, but when I try train, I get the errors that I couldn't solve even after googling long time..Please help!
Here's my version info : Anaconda2, Cuda 7.5, Cudnn 4, Visual Studio 2013

```
C:\caffe-master\Build\x64\Release>caffe train -solver=cifar10_quick_solver.prototxt
[libprotobuf ERROR ..\src\google\protobuf\text_format.cc:274] Error parsing text
-format caffe.SolverParameter: 4:10: Invalid escape sequence in string literal.
[libprotobuf ERROR ..\src\google\protobuf\text_format.cc:274] Error parsing text
-format caffe.SolverParameter: 4:23: Invalid escape sequence in string literal.
[libprotobuf ERROR ..\src\google\protobuf\text_format.cc:274] Error parsing text
-format caffe.SolverParameter: 4:32: Invalid escape sequence in string literal.
[libprotobuf ERROR ..\src\google\protobuf\text_format.cc:274] Error parsing text
-format caffe.SolverParameter: 4:40: Invalid escape sequence in string literal.
[libprotobuf ERROR ..\src\google\protobuf\text_format.cc:274] Error parsing text
-format caffe.SolverParameter: 24:22: Invalid escape sequence in string literal.

[libprotobuf ERROR ..\src\google\protobuf\text_format.cc:274] Error parsing text
-format caffe.SolverParameter: 24:35: Invalid escape sequence in string literal.

[libprotobuf ERROR ..\src\google\protobuf\text_format.cc:274] Error parsing text
-format caffe.SolverParameter: 24:44: Invalid escape sequence in string literal.

[libprotobuf ERROR ..\src\google\protobuf\text_format.cc:274] Error parsing text
-format caffe.SolverParameter: 24:52: Invalid escape sequence in string literal.

F1019 14:25:21.171140  5692 upgrade_proto.cpp:1063] Check failed: ReadProtoFromT
extFile(param_file, param) Failed to parse SolverParameter file: cifar10_quick_solver.prototxt
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
```

I also tried to update prototxt using upgrade_net_proto_binary, upgrade_net_proto_text, upgrade_solver_proto_text, I get the error...

```
C:\caffe-master\Build\x64\Release>upgrade_solver_proto_text c:\caffe-master\examples\cifar10\cifar10_full_solver.prototxt cifar10_full_new_solver.prototxt

[libprotobuf ERROR ..\src\google\protobuf\text_format.cc:274] Error parsing text
-format caffe.SolverParameter: 25:22: Invalid escape sequence in string literal.

[libprotobuf ERROR ..\src\google\protobuf\text_format.cc:274] Error parsing text
-format caffe.SolverParameter: 25:35: Invalid escape sequence in string literal.

[libprotobuf ERROR ..\src\google\protobuf\text_format.cc:274] Error parsing text
-format caffe.SolverParameter: 25:44: Invalid escape sequence in string literal.

[libprotobuf ERROR ..\src\google\protobuf\text_format.cc:274] Error parsing text
-format caffe.SolverParameter: 25:52: Invalid escape sequence in string literal.

E1018 20:49:33.715873  5896 upgrade_solver_proto_text.cpp:30] Failed to parse in
put text file as SolverParameter: c:\caffe-master\examples\cifar10\cifar10_full_solver.prototxt
```

Answer (score 0):

After all those trials and errors, I got the answer.
For those who suffer the same thing, please refer.

at the solver file, I have indicated the source file and mean file to absolute address.
But the mistake I made is, I have written the address with \ not /.
Even I type in the command in cmd window with using \, in the prototxt, it does not allow it.

So you should write the address in prototxt file, with /.
i.e. C:/caffe-master/examples/cifar10/cifar10_full_train.prototxt.

Cheers.

Comment: or you can write`\\ ` instead of a single `\\`